# How do I close a window from an application but not quit the application

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script, applescript

I'm trying to have a shell script run and then close itself but not quit Terminal all together. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ "$JOB_NUMBER" = '' ]; do
    echo -n "++++++++++++++++++++Job Number: "
    read -e JOB_NUMBER
done

echo "Opening Job Number: $JOB_NUMBER's folder"
open -g /Volumes/OSX_0*/$JOB_NUMBER*
sleep .5
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' & exit
```

but the AppleScript here quits Terminal where I'm just trying to close that window

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it,

1. In Terminal, find a preset profile you like and make a duplicate of it.
2. Under `shell` section, tick `Run command:` and enter your script
3. Untick `Run inside shell`, and below this
4. Select `Close if the shell exited cleanly`
5. Make any additional changes and...
6. Export it to a `.terminal` file.

The result is a custom window, colors, size etc that will close once your script exits successfully (ie exit code 0). You can also remove the Applescript bits from your script.

You can now launch your script with `open AutoClose.Terminal` or just double click it from Finder.

[image]